# How do I get my image centered without overlapping my text in html & css

Tags: html, css

I'm having a very difficult time getting my image centered and responsive without overlapping my text. How do I fix this.

[View the issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyLB9.jpg)

```css
div.shadow {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 45%;
    max-height: 45%;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    overflow: visible;
}
img.logo {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-top: -50%;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'existencelight';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Welcome to Nepali Kitchen</h1>
</header>
<div class="shadow"><img class="logo" src="bg3.jpg" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have position absolute in your div  so  you can adjust the top value

```
div.shadow {
 position: absolute;
 max-width: 45%;
 max-height: 45%;
 top: 200px;  /* just a sample  with a fixed  pixel value */
 left:50%;
 overflow: visible;
}
```

or try using

```
 position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

That image should probably be a background instead.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'existencelight';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png') center top no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Welcome to Nepali Kitchen</h1>
</header>
```

Or you can move that image behind the text by modifying the z-index.

```css
div.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 45%;
  max-height: 45%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: visible;
}

img.logo {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-top: -50%;
  margin-left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'existencelight';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Welcome to Nepali Kitchen</h1>
</header>
<div class="shadow"><img class="logo" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the positioning of your elements.

If you want to have a fixed header your content needs to be pushed down the height of your header. Do this by wrapping your content in a container, and giving it a `margin-top` equal to the `height` of your header.

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
}

.content-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px; 
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<header></header>
<div class="content-container">
</div>
```

Give your content-container the `position: relative`. If you want to center items in the center you can either use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or give it a `margin: 0px auto;`.

Position relative means it's *positioned relative to other elements*.

Some other things I noticed in your code which could be done better/cleaner:

- Use the units `em` or `rem` for `font-size`
- It's not necessary to prefix your classes with the element (div.shadow -> .shadow and img.logo -> .logo)
- Also I would recommend ordering your CSS following the [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). This opts for much cleaner code and better readability.

This means you will get something like this:

```
.class {
    // Positioning first
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    // It's size
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;

    // It's margin
    margin: 0px auto;

    // It's border
    border: 1px solid blue;

    // It's padding
    padding: 2em 0;

    // Content styling
    color: #676766;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't know why you have written this complex css. It can be possible by some easy css coding.

<style>
div.shadow {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
img.logo {

}
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'existencelight';
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
</style>
```